# Using typeof to check for object properties not working

Tags: javascript, typeof

I have an object that I need to check the properties to see if they are all `strings` and if so return `true`, but mine always returns `true`.

```
function StringsObj(x) {
        for (var prop in x) {
            if(typeof x[prop] === "string") {
                return true;
                }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    } 

var student = {
        name: "Judy",
        class: "freshman",
        age: 19,
        honors: true
    };

StringsObj(student)
```

Comment: Why are you returning true as soon as you find a single string property?

Comment: your function will only ever check the first property if it is string

Comment: Yes - I understand now that I should have always returned true by default and only check for an exception instead of checking for each case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because after the first check you function returns  `true` (`"Judy"` is of string type) and stops executing. You can do something like this :

```
function StringsObj(x) {
    for (var prop in x) {
        if(typeof x[prop] !== "string") {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3TpE/1/)